# Setting default PHP Executeable Path in Atom

Tags: php, atom-editor

I'm installing a lot of PHP packages but all of it always needs me to set the PHP path manually, Even tho they use `Default: php` in their `PHP Executeable Path`, How can i change the default path?

Answer (score -1):

This depends on what operating system you use. For Windows it is the executable path `C:\folder\php.exe`. For Unix systems, like Mac or Linux, it is just `php`.